# Looking at ball of radius $r$ in $ℝ^n$

Tags: number-theory

> Show that volume of the ball of radius $r$ in $ℝ^n$ is equal to $vr^n$ where $v$ is some constant. Show that the surface area of the ball of radius $r$ in $ℝ^n$  is equal to $sr^{n-1}$ for some constant $s$.

Comment: Do you know how to find it for the special case $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: As stated, this is just a result about scaling. That is, if $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\lambda$ is some constant, then $m (\lambda A) = |\lambda|^n mA$.